# Why in Hebrew masculine nouns agree with feminine numbers and vice verse?

Tags: number, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

Also in other semitic languages, see [Why do feminine-looking numbers agree with masculine nouns and vice versa in Hebrew and Arabic?](https://www.quora.com/Semitic-Languages-Why-do-feminine-looking-numbers-agree-with-masculine-nouns-and-vice-versa-in-Hebrew-and-Arabic). As other languages seemingly stemmed from Biblical Hebrew (Loshon Hakodesh), what is the reason (secret meaning) of this polarity?

Note: I am not simply asking for an explanation of the grammatical phenomenon, but for Jewish sources who give some Jewish approach to this phenomenon of the Hebrew language.

Comment: It is not true that Arabic developed from Hebrew, please read the basics here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_languages

Comment: That's why I said Loshon Hakodesh - presumably, the language that preceded the creation.

Comment: "As other languages seemingly stemmed from Biblical Hebrew" detailing why you think this would be the case would improve the question.

Comment: Questions about Hebrew are off-topic. If you could please explain why this is related to Judaism, I would be more than happy to rescind my vote to close.

Comment: I added a comment clarifying why it is arguably a question about Judaism, not about Hebrew or grammar. If you disagree with the edit, roll it back...

Comment: @Doniel - I don't know how can you set Hebrew off-topic if this *is the language of Judaism*. As all other human languages are thought to be arbitrary, Hebrew is the language of Creation and the Torah. I don't think it's fare to stamp Rashi's "דברה התורה בלשון בני אדם" on every question, equaling Hebrew to other languages. As such, you can rephrase it with: "*Why Torah uses ...*.

Comment: @AlBerko “I don’t know how can you set Hebrew off-topic if this is the language of Judaism.” Sorry, I didn’t make the rules. The [list of impermissible topics](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) very clearly states that “questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are about ... Hebrew language ... are generally off-topic.” (Con’t)

Comment: (Con’t) As per (cc) @mevaqesh’s edit, tacking on “what does the Torah say about this” has already been [discussed in meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4373/). At the moment, the policy seems to stand at you have to explain why you might think that’s a valid question. You can’t just ask about using נה for plural feminine, nor can you just ask what the Torah has to say on it; you have to explain why you think the Torah would discuss it and thereby support the question.